# Helping the JVM with stack allocation by using separate objects

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, stack

I have a bottleneck method which attempts to add points (as x-y pairs) to a HashSet.  The common case is that the set already contains the point in which case nothing happens.  Should I use a separate point for adding from the one I use for checking if the set already contains it?  It seems this would allow the JVM to allocate the checking-point on stack.  Thus in the common case, this will require no heap allocation.

Ex.  I'm considering changing

```
HashSet<Point> set;

public void addPoint(int x, int y) {
    if(set.add(new Point(x,y))) {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

to

```
HashSet<Point> set;
public void addPoint(int x, int y){
    if(!set.contains(new Point(x,y))) {
        set.add(new Point(x,y));
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a profiler which will tell me whether objects are allocated on heap or stack?

EDIT:  To clarify why I think the second might be faster, in the first case the object may or may not be added to the collection, so it's not non-escaping and cannot be optimized.  In the second case, the first object allocated is clearly non-escaping so it can be optimized by the JVM and put on stack.  The second allocation only occurs in the rare case where it's not already contained.

Comment: Objects are always on heap. Reference will be on stack.

Comment: I don't see why the second code should be better concerning performance or memory usage! You're creating the point twice if it's not already contained. Usually, all objects are created on the heap (there are different kinds of 'heaps', it depends on the VM). Only in case of escape analysis, the VM might decide to not 'really' create the first point.

Comment: I thought the JVM could identify non-escaping objects and allocate them on stack.  See this article: http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=64  I'm trying to help the JVM out by making my object non-escaping

Comment: Yes, but you should not rely on that.

Comment: Why not?  What's wrong with my argument?

Comment: @dspyz: You're putting them into a `HashSet`, so they're by definition escaping.  What you're running into is the per-object overhead inherent to Java programming.  To get around it, you have to write some very ugly copypasta that you specialise on every type you're going to use---just so you can store primitives instead of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marko Topolnik properly answered your question; the space allocated for the first `new Point` may or may not be immediately freed and it is probably foolish to bank on it happening.  But I want to expand on why you're currently in a deep state of sin:

You're trying to optimise this the wrong way.

You've identified object creation to be the bottleneck here.  I'm going to assume that you're right about this.  You're hoping that, if you create fewer objects, the code will run faster.  That might be true, but it will never run very fast as you've designed it.

Every object in Java has a pretty fat header (16 bytes; an 8-byte "mark word" full of bit fields and an 8-byte pointer to the class type) and, depending on what's happened in your program thus far, possibly another pretty fat trailer.  Your HashSet isn't storing just the contents of your objects; it's storing pointers to those fat-headers-followed-by-contents.  (Actually, it's storing pointers to `Entry` classes that themselves store pointers to `Point`s.  Two levels of indirection there.)

A `HashSet` lookup, then, figures out which bucket it needs to look at and then chases one pointer per thing in the bucket to do the comparison.  (As one great big chain in series.)  There probably aren't very many of these objects, but they almost certainly aren't stored close together, making your cache angry.  Note that object allocation in Java is extremely cheap---you just increment a pointer---and that this is quite probably a bigger source of slowness.

Java doesn't provide any abstraction like C++'s templates, so the only real way to make this fast and still provide the `Set` abstraction is to copy `HashSet`'s code, change all of the data structures to represent your objects inline, modify the methods to work with the new data structures, and, if you're still worried, make copies of the relevant methods that take a list of parameters corresponding to object contents (i.e. `contains(int, int)`) that do the right thing without constructing a new object.

This approach is error-prone and time-consuming, but it's necessary unfortunately often when working on Java projects where performance matters.  Take a look at the Trove library Marko mentioned and see if you can use it instead; Trove did exactly this for the primitive types.

With that out of the way, a monomorphic call site is one where only one method is called.  Hotspot aggressively inlines calls from monomorphic call sites.  You'll notice that `HashSet.contains` punts to `HashMap.containsKey`.  You'd better pray for `HashMap.containsKey` to be inlined since you need the `hashCode` call and `equals` calls inside to be monomorphic.  You can verify that your code is being compiled nicely by using the `-XX:+PrintAssembly` option and poring over the output, but it's probably not---and even if it is, it's probably still slow because of what a `HashSet` is.

Comment: Object header is just 8 or 16 bytes.

Comment: @leventov: Oops, yeah.  You're right that the overhead isn't all header.  I fixed that.  (But:  In order to preserve the hash code during gc (and locking and so forth), the JVM sets the `hashCode` field in the mark word to "look past the object" if it needs that space.  Also, if you've used the object's monitor (`synchronized`, `wait`, `notify`, etc.), the normal header has been relocated someplace else and replaced with a pointer to the monitor.  All of this, monitor included, adds up to quite a bit more than the 6 or 7 words I initially claimed, though they're not stored in the header.)

Comment: 1) just 8 bytes on 32bit VM. 2) When we discuss struct-like classes in Java, we typically override `hashCode()` so that it isn't stored in the object header and don't lock on its instances.

Comment: @leventov: 1) It's 2013; nobody should still use 32-bit Java.  2) The identity hash code still exists and must remain consistent across a GC.  You seem to be trying to get me to conduct a best-case analysis here---we *might* only need 8 bytes *if* you run a 32-bit JVM *and* the GC never runs *and* you never synchronise on the object.  While OP's proposed use of `Point` almost certainly doesn't involve synchronising on the `Point`, we cannot discount ill-timed garbage collections or assume that the GC will notice that our temporary `Point` is garbage immediately---we must account for the space.

Comment: `Point` class must be 1) immutable, synchronization never needed. Because of experience of OO design in Java (remember `java.awt.Dimension`?) Anyway, we must not modify objects added to the set or map. 2) `hashCode()` defined as `xCoord() ^ yCoord()`, *not default hashCode() impl*, if OP consider construction separate objects for insertion into the set, isn't it?

Comment: @leventov: Well-designed Java code can avoid bloating small objects beyond what's needed by the header itself, sure.  What happens when you run a JVMTI tool that walks the heap or something on it?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have written `new Point(x,y)`, you are creating a new object. It may happen not to be placed on the heap, but that's just a bet you can lose. For example, the `contains` call should be inlined for the escape analysis to work, or at least it should be a monomorphic call site. All this means that you are optimizing against a quite erratic performance model.

If you want to avoid allocation the solid way, you can use Trove library's `TLongHashSet` and have your `(int,int)` pairs encoded as single `long` values.

Comment: The "Point" was actually just an example.  My object is slightly more complicated than that.  I realize that there may be better approaches, but I want to know whether my argument is sound.  What's a "monomorphic call site"?  Where can I read more about this?

Comment: Google will not let you down.